# Can I make use of Git for developing with only FTP access

Tags: git, version-control, ftp

I do freelance work on dozens of small businesses websites at any one time. Generally their setups require local databases and other server configurations so I have to develop and test directly on their servers.

Currently I mount the client's server via FTP (using Transmit) and, make changes and test directly on a development copy of the site on their server and copy files over to the live version when I am satisfied that they work.

Without shell access (some are even Windows based servers) is there a way that I could work Git into my workflow to maintain a versioned history of the site?

**Edit:** Since I have their web folder mounted as a volume on my machine, could I just use their development sub-folder as my git staging directory? I could make changes and test them directly and then commit without any extra steps.

Would having Git's hidden files in the web path be a security problem? Would the fact that files are remote cause Git to run prohibitively slowly? Assuming I am the only one developing on the server, this seems like a plausible solution.

Comment: If you can't create a separate environment for development, you're really asking for trouble (and lots of it). You should look into getting a local environment going first, then using git in that environment.

Comment: @Nic Because each client's setup is different (server settings, software versions, operating systems) I have to work and test on their server or I will miss all kinds of problems. Is there some way around this that I am missing?

Comment: I've never encountered a setup that I couldn't replicate locally - some have been more challenging than others (for example, a really poorly designed ColdFusion webapp), but the key is having something in a local environment that you have total control over. You can really dive into it and sync your changes over ftp automatically, but I'd really try to make a local environment. For things like databases, you can always connect your local copy to their development database. Just get a copy of the codebase up locally so you can get some sort of version control on there.

Comment: @Nic Unfortunately (for me!) many of these clients are small businesses (restaurants, lawyers, non-profits) for whom I am only doing ~4-10 hours of work. Setting up a local version of their setup on my machine, especially when I may not know which of it's unique "features" will be problematic, would probably take more time than the work I have been hired to do. I whole-heartedly agree that local development would be the best practice, but I have to consider the overhead.

Comment: Have you seen [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp)?

Comment: @GregBacon I did see that, but won't that only let me push a local copy to the server? The problem is that my changes are happening ON the server.

Comment: I don't think your solution suggested in your edit will help much - and having the hidden `.git` file in the webroot is a critical security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If keeping a clone of the repository on the client machines isn't a requirement: since you seem to only work on and test your changes locally, you should just setup a git repository for each client on your (local) development machine that will serve to track your changes. Then once you've changed/committed/tested, fall back to your current means of copying the changes using FTP. You'll get the benefits of source control immediately, and you can always setup git sharing on client machines later, if there is any reason to have clones of the repository on those machines. The really important thing is getting your projects into *any* repository.

Otherwise if you must have repo clones on the client machines there is a quick alternative: git installs typically support `git-daemon` which allows client/server TCP access to a repository. No authentication though so it's really best to only use on a localnet; hence this is really not a viable solution in your case.

A better solution would be to setup some sort of ssh server on the client windows machines and then configure git access across ssh. There are a couple of commercial products have tried to make this turnkey on Windows: [WindowsGit](http://windowsgit.com/), [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/). Both are payware.

If you look around you'll find some tutorials for doing this yourself. [Here](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) is one.

This does not address setting up ssh access on platforms other than Windows, but typically setting up ssh on Windows is the difficult task.

Naturally, any solution will initially require **some** access to the client machines to at least setup git.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your thoughtful response, but I'm not sure about one piece. If have the repository on my local (client) machine, do I have to copy the entire project (or remember to copy every individual file I've touched) to my local machine every time I want to commit?

Comment: Jordan: my answer assumes that you were doing changes and testing locally (**not** on a remote client machine), as per Nic's comments, and then copying over the changes to the client. Either I misunderstood your workflow before your edits to your question or your edits clarified that you're editing/testing on each client's machine. I'll try to edit my answer to reflect that.